# HSTS Super Cookie Implementation

Tags: java, php, ssl, cookies, https

I'm looking to implement the HSTS "Super Cookie" into my website so that the user doesn't have to fill out a particular form every time they go to the website: an SQL database will map their HSTS "Super Cookie" code to their previous form submission and will fill out the fields with the saved data.

I've checked all over Google for implementation, but I can't find it anywhere. Could someone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HSTS "super cookie" is primarily a theoretical privacy-breaking attack. It is not actually intended for use in production to identify users — reading and writing the values it stores is a rather slow operation, as it requires establishing connections with dozens of HTTPS servers. (This means that it is also rather complex to configure, as it requires that you operate all of these servers.) Additionally, as it is considered an attack, it is likely that future browsers may implement measures to prevent it from working at all.

Use normal cookies to identify users.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](http://insidethecpu.com/2016/01/29/hsts-supercookies-with-asp-net/) outlines an implementation of HSTS Supercookies in an ASP.NET application. The solution leverages 4 external domains, yielding a potential 24 unique IDs. Extending the solution to leverage 32 domains will yield a potential 2.6 billion unique IDs. The code necessary to read and write HSTS values is explained and provided [in full in GitHub](https://github.com/daishisystems/SuperCookieSimpleTest).